# Advise on loose coupling between user controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 5 user controls on the page and each control implements it's own interface that contains properties and events. In order to enable communication between user controls, I am creating a property of target user control inside other user control. Through this property, it's state can be altered and be able to register its events.

Below is the pseudo code of results user control. It subscribes to OnSearch event of Search user control.

```
public interface IResults
{
     //other fields
    ISearch SearchControl { get;}
}

public partial class Results : IResults
{
     //other fields

     public ISearch SearchControl
     {

        get{
        this.Page.Parent.FindControl("UCSearch") as ISearch;}
     }

     protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        this.SearchControl.OnSearch += new EventHandler(testMethod);
     }
}
```

1. Is it ok to have the reference properties inside user controls to subscribe to the events and manipulating the state. Does it create any maintenance problem in future.
2. Does FindControl and type casting degrade the performance of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's OK to register events from one object from inside another object. That's what they are for. :D

2) There would be a small amount of overhead involved performing the search each time `SearchControl` in accessed. I doubt it would be of any significance, depending, of course, how frequently `SearchControl` is called.

However, how you have implemented `SearchControl` will present some maintenance problems in the future. By violating [the Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) in `SearchControl` you have tightly coupled your code to a `Page` class that has a control named `"UCSearch"`.

Instead why don't you include the a set accessor for the `SearchControl` property, and have the parent provide the value of `SearchControl`. Not only would this make the the code easier to maintain, but it is more loosely coupled, and also avoids your performance concerns! As an added bonus it will be easy to create unit test for!!!

```
public interface IResults
{
     //other fields
    ISearch SearchControl { get; set; }
}


public partial class Results : IResults
{
     //other fields

     private ISearch searchControl;

     public ISearch SearchControl
     {
        get
        {
            return this.searchControl;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.SearchControl != null)
            {
                this.SearchControl.OnSearch -= new EventHandler(testMethod);
            }

            this.searchControl = value;

            this.SearchControl.OnSearch += new EventHandler(testMethod);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. In an article, I read that if there are multiple user controls on a page, the main page should handle the interaction. Right now, what I have is when search event is raised, the results control will interact with db and populate the results. I am thinking if I move it to main page, is there any benefits over what I am doing now. Any thoughts?

Comment: And why should we remove the event in set method if the SearchControl is not null

Comment: You're very welcome. I have expanded my example to include how, in my mind, the interface could be implemented. 

What you have outlined, responding to a search within the UserControl, sounds. It encapsulated all the required functionality within a single object. If you ever wanted to change how to response to the event you should then only need to make changes to a single object!

Comment: Removing event handlers when they are no longer required will reduce the number reference to an object, and this will assist the garbage collector to determine if it is safe to remove an object from memory.

Comment: So does the check needs to be for not null or null for removing the handler.

Comment: Not null. It's checking if `SearchControl` already has a value. If so remove the existing event handler.